# Google Cloud Monitoring - E-mail icon error

Tags: google-cloud-monitoring

We have encountered an issue with the icon displayed in the incident alert emails we receive. The icon appears to be broken in both the notification for new incident alerts and the emails indicating that an incident has been resolved.

[image]

Please inform the Google Cloud team to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can send a report on the google support team to further investigate the issue, you may refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers) to help you.